# Scala: Having a filter, selecting the values from another column

Tags: scala

First of all I'm using Scala on IntelliJ. Having this:

```
type     |  age
electric |  30
diesel   |  24
gasoline |  28
diesel   |  31
```

I would like to define a function that gets the average of the column "age", excluding the type "electric". I don't know how to filter one column and then operate in the other column maintaining the filter. For now, I've made this:

```
  def nonelectric (c: Seq[Df]): Double = {
    val cars = c.map(k => k.type)
    val nonelectriccars = cars.filterNot(cars=> cars == "electric")
    var a:Double = 0.0
    for (i <- nonelectriccars){
      a += i
    }
    a/nonelectriccars.size.toDouble
  }
```

But, of course, I can't get the mean from the "string" type. How could I fix my code?

Comment: Don't drop the `age` info (as you do in the first `.map()`) before the `filterNot()`. Filter on `car => car.type == "electric"`. This way the `nonelectriccars` still has the info you need in the for-loop (whether you `map(car => car.age)`  or `a += i.age`).

Comment: Thanks, and how could I select both columns in the ```.map()``` ?

Comment: Assuming you have more than 2 columns, you don't really need to drop any other columns at all (at least not in your question). Still, if you want to keep only a couple of columns, `.map(car => (car.type, car.age))` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Df` is a `class` with fields `carType` and `value` then this is a possible solution:

```
def nonelectric(c: Seq[Df]): Double = {
  val nonelectriccars =
    c.collect { case df if df.carType != "electric" => df.value }

  if (nonelectriccars.isEmpty) {
    0.0
  } else {
    nonelectriccars.sum.toDouble / nonelectriccars.length
  }
}
```

`collect` is a useful method than can combine a `filter` operation and a `map` operation using a partial function.

If DF is actually a dataframe then this is a Spark question and I can't help!